# How to start GWT from web service REST

Tags: java, web-services, rest, gwt

Is it possible to run GWT application from web service REST?

```
@Path("/main")
public class RestService {
  @GET
  @Path("{name}")
  public Response getUserByName(@PathParam("name") String name){

   // return Response.status(200).entity("My name is " + name).build();
  }
}
```

What is important for me, the URL which calls REST, must not be changed after GWT will run. So when the browser go to `localhost:8080/application/main/adam`, the REST runs and calls the GWT application which shows message box with `My name is adam`. After that, I can sill see the same URL in the browser.

Maybe I should explain the reason of my requirements. 
I want to create application where the end-user will use only the URLs, example:

`localhost:8080/application/somecommand/somedata`

`localhost:8080/application/anothercommand/anotherdata`

No windows, no forms, only URLs.

Comment: GWT runs inside a browser, for the most part. So you have to load a URL into the browser first. Only then would the GWT application (which loaded from that URL) call a web service, in this case RESTful. Perhaps you need to explain what you are thinking. If I can't understand it, perhaps others are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just serve the HTML page with your GWT app.

Answer (score 0):

If you can deal with Urls Like this:

localhost:8080/application#somecommand/somedata
localhost:8080/application#anothercommand/anotherdata

It is just the GWT [History-API](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory?hl=de)